# How can I make some questions in a form required, depending on the questions answered?

Tags: php, sql, validation, input

Depending on which questions are filled out, I want to make half the inputs required and the other half to leave empty.

Basically I have a form like this:

```
//first set
        <p>Source: <input type="text" name="source" class="task_input"></p>
        <p>Date Earned: <input type="text" name="date_earned" class="task_input"></p>
        <p>Amount Earned: <input type="text" name="earned" class="task_input"></p>


 //second set
            <p>Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient" class="task_input"></p>
            <p>Date Given: <input type="text" name="date_given" class="task_input"></p>
            <p>Amount Given: <input type="text" name="given" class="task_input"></p>
```

and I want the user to either fill out the first set or the second set, and fill out all 3 of whatever the user chooses.
I have an if statement set up for errors that looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if ((empty($_POST['source'])||($_POST['date_earned'])||($_POST['earned']))&&(empty($_POST['recipient'])&&($_POST['date_given'])&&($_POST['given']))){
    $errors = "Looks like you left something out...";
}elseif ((empty($_POST['recipient'])||($_POST['date_given'])||($_POST['given']))&&(empty($_POST['source'])&&($_POST['date_earned'])&&($_POST['earned']))){
    $errors = "Looks like you left something out...";
}else{
//submit
```

The issue is that it sends an error message if anything is left empty, even though I tried to split it up. My other option is to take away all error messages, but that means that any or all of the three required inputs could be left empty with no error message.

How should I write this if-statement so I can get the results I need?

Comment: `empty($_POST['source'])||($_POST['date_earned'])` means *if source is empty __or date_earned is truthy__*…! “`empty`” does not implicitly propagate to all the other values.

Comment: So the correct way to write it would be      (empty($_POST['source']))||(empty($_POST['date_earned']))  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, with some fairly simple javascript, cajole the user into completing one section or another by ensuring that the alternative inputs are disabled as soon as input is identified in any single input element. This would not negate the need for validation serverside as it is easy to disable javascript or process a form by other meas ( ie: curl etc) but could be useful as the initial interface.

You can see the effect in the snippet below.

```js
const d=document;
const bttn=d.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

d.addEventListener('input',e=>{
  // fetch the parent node and it's data-id value
  let section=e.target.closest('section')
  let id=Number( section.dataset.id );
  
  // make sure button is disabled
  bttn.disabled=true;
  
  // use the data-id value to find the other section using 1 - x logic
  // and disable all inputs within that other section. The user can now
  // only complete entries in one or other section at a time.
  let alt=d.querySelectorAll(`section[ data-id="${1-id}" ] input`)
      alt.forEach(input=>{
        input.disabled=true;
      });
  
  
  
  // find inputs within current section and convert nodelist to an array
  let col=[ ...section.querySelectorAll('input') ];
  // find the initial number of input elements in the array.
  let len=col.length;
  // filter the array to remove empty (&/or other criteria) inputs.
  col=col.filter( input=>input.value!='' );
  
  // If all inputs are cleared, the other section should be re-enabled.    
  if( col.length==0 )alt.forEach(input=>{
    input.disabled=false;
  });
  
  // enable the button if all fields are populated.
  if( col.length==len ){
    bttn.disabled=false;
  }
})
```

```css
section,label{display:block; box-sizing:border-box; padding:0.25rem}
section{margin:1rem 0}
label{ width:50%; margin:0.1rem 0 }
label input{float:right}
```

```html
<form method='post'>

  <section data-id=0>
    <label>Source: <input type="text" name="source" class="task_input" /></label>
    <label>Date Earned: <input type="text" name="date_earned" class="task_input" /></label>
    <label>Amount Earned: <input type="text" name="earned" class="task_input" /></label>
  </section>
  
  <section data-id=1>
    <label>Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient" class="task_input" /></label>
    <label>Date Given: <input type="text" name="date_given" class="task_input" /></label>
    <label>Amount Given: <input type="text" name="given" class="task_input" /></label>
  </section>

  <input type='submit' disabled />
  
</form>
```

And to process the form data, rather than multiple `isset` or `empty` calls where the logic might become overly confusing you could check whether the keys submitted

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        $errors=array();
        
        $sets=array(
            array('source','date_earned','earned'),
            array('recipient','date_given','given')
        );
        
        # filter the POST array to remove empty items.
        $_POST=array_filter( $_POST );
        
        # if no elements are populated abandon processing.
        if( empty( $_POST ) )echo '<h3>Empty POST - one or other set of inputs must be completed</h3>';
        else{
            
            # arbitary but take the first key in the POST array. If other keys are not in the same set there is a problem.
            $keys=array_keys( $_POST );
            $key=$keys[0];
            $set=in_array( $key, $sets[0] ) ? $sets[0] : $sets[1];
            
            
            # loop through the POST array, if any field is not in the same set as the first array key, it is an error.
            foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){
                if( !in_array( $field, $set ) )$errors[ $field ]='Incorrect set';
                if( empty( $value ) && !in_array( $field, $set ) )$errors[ $field ]='Incorrect set &amp; also empty';
            }
            
            # make sure that all fields from selected set are not empty, otherwise it is an error.
            foreach( $set as $field ){
                if( empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) )$errors[ $field ]='Cannot be empty';
            }
            
            if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                #handle errors in some manner.
                foreach( $errors as $field => $errmsg )printf('<div>%s: %s</div>', $field, $errmsg );
            }else{
                #celebrate
                echo '<h3>That is acceptable</h3>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```